# For loop overwriting object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having some trouble here.

I have an array full of objects. This is my input

```
[
 { id: 1, colour: 'blue', count: 10 },
 { id: 1, colour: 'red', count: 12 },
 { id: 2, colour: 'red', count': 8 },
 { id: 2, colour: 'blue', count: 3 }
]
```

My goal is for every object that is enetered in the array, to parse according to ID and deliver in a more freindly (to me) format. 
It should like like this

```
{"id":1, "colour_count":{"blue":10,"red":12}}
{"id":2, "colour_count":{"blue":8,"red":3}}
```

And so on as i get more IDs.

Here is my current code. In this case the array is i. My problem is that i am overwiting the data object.

```
let data = {
   colour_count: {}
}

for( var i=0; i<row.length; i++) {
   (function(i) { 
      data["colour_count"][row[i].colour] = row[i].count
      data["id"] = row[i].id      
   })(i)
}
```

Can anybody help me reach my desired output?

Comment: Well, you're writing to the `data` object so, of course it will be changed.  It's not clear exactly what the problem is or what the desired output is.  Please show the exact Javascript object notation for the desired output.  Your current results just show two separate objects.  Are they supposed to be in an array?  Are you trying to make a new object instead of writing to the `data` object?

Comment: Also, why are you using an IIFE in your `for` loop?   Is there actually an asynchronous function involved in this?

Comment: In your current code, where does `row` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with two parts. Firstly, create a hash based on the id, so it is easy to lookup and set:

```
const hash = rows.reduce((result, { id, colour, count }) => {
  if(!result[id]){
    result[id] = {
      id,
      colour_count: {}
    }
  }
  result[id].colour_count[colour] = count
  return result
}, {})
```

Then map the values to an array

```
const arr = Object.values(hash)
```

Working source:

```js
const rows = [
 { id: 1, colour: 'blue', count: 10 },
 { id: 1, colour: 'red', count: 12 },
 { id: 2, colour: 'red', count: 8 },
 { id: 2, colour: 'blue', count: 3 }
]

const hash = rows.reduce((result, { id, colour, count }) => {
  if(!result[id]){
    result[id] = {
      id,
      colour_count: {}
    }
  }
  result[id].colour_count[colour] = count
  return result
}, {})

const arr = Object.values(hash)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the grouping and calculate the totals then just use `Object.values` to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, colour: 'blue', count: 10 }, { id: 1, colour: 'red', count: 12 }, { id: 2, colour: 'red', count: 8 }, { id: 2, colour: 'blue', count: 3 } ] 

const result = data.reduce((r,{id, colour, count}) => {
  r[id] = ({ id, colour_count: 
     Object.assign(r[id] ? r[id].colour_count : {}, {[colour]: 0}) })
  r[id].colour_count[colour] += count
  return r
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(result))
```